# ESP32 failing to detect PN532 NFC module

Tags: nfc, i2c, esp32

I've been struggling for the past few days to get the Elechouse PN532 V3 module working with an ESP32 over I2C. The PN532 module itself works fine with a Raspberry Pi.

This is the circuit (not actually using SparkFun ESP32 board, just for reference)
[image: ESP32 circuit]

And this is the code I'm trying to run

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <PN532_I2C.h>
#include <PN532.h>
#include <NfcAdapter.h>

PN532_I2C pn532i2c(Wire);
PN532 nfc(pn532i2c);

void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Hello!");

  Wire.begin(18, 19);
  nfc.begin();

  uint32_t versiondata = nfc.getFirmwareVersion();
  if (! versiondata) {
    Serial.print("Didn't find PN53x board");
    while (1); // halt
  }

  // Got ok data, print it out!
  Serial.print("Found chip PN5"); Serial.println((versiondata>>24) & 0xFF, HEX); 
  Serial.print("Firmware ver. "); Serial.print((versiondata>>16) & 0xFF, DEC); 
  Serial.print('.'); Serial.println((versiondata>>8) & 0xFF, DEC);

  // Set the max number of retry attempts to read from a card
  // This prevents us from waiting forever for a card, which is
  // the default behaviour of the PN532.
  nfc.setPassiveActivationRetries(0xFF);

  // configure board to read RFID tags
  nfc.SAMConfig();

  Serial.println("Waiting for an ISO14443A card");
}

void loop(void) {
  boolean success;
  uint8_t uid[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };  // Buffer to store the returned UID
  uint8_t uidLength;                        // Length of the UID (4 or 7 bytes depending on ISO14443A card type)

  // Wait for an ISO14443A type cards (Mifare, etc.).  When one is found
  // 'uid' will be populated with the UID, and uidLength will indicate
  // if the uid is 4 bytes (Mifare Classic) or 7 bytes (Mifare Ultralight)
  success = nfc.readPassiveTargetID(PN532_MIFARE_ISO14443A, &uid[0], &uidLength);

  if (success) {
    Serial.println("Found a card!");
    Serial.print("UID Length: ");Serial.print(uidLength, DEC);Serial.println(" bytes");
    Serial.print("UID Value: ");
    for (uint8_t i=0; i < uidLength; i++) 
    {
      Serial.print(" 0x");Serial.print(uid[i], HEX); 
    }
    Serial.println("");
    // Wait 1 second before continuing
    delay(1000);
  }
  else
  {
    // PN532 probably timed out waiting for a card
    Serial.println("Timed out waiting for a card");
  }
}
```

And finally the serial output: `Didn't find PN53X board`
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: libraries im using https://github.com/elechouse/PN532 and the ESP32 dev board is a Wemos Lolin32 Lite clone.

Comment: Hey, were you able to find out the reason 'cause I am having the same issue? And also doesn't esp32 have internal pull ups?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any of this hardware to verify this, but from 'PN532-PN532_HSU\NDEF\README.md'

```
For the Adafruit Shield using I2C 

    #include <Wire.h>
    #include <PN532_I2C.h>
    #include <PN532.h>
    #include <NfcAdapter.h>

    PN532_I2C pn532_i2c(Wire);
    NfcAdapter nfc = NfcAdapter(pn532_i2c);
```

Try using the above in your code? I'd also suggest you review the PN532 I2C examples in more depth. The PN532 I2C library code defines a 'wakeup' function:

```
void PN532_I2C::wakeup()
{
    delay(500); // wait for all ready to manipulate pn532
}
```

The comment makes me believe the device may require a significant delay (500ms) before it's ready to talk.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

sda and scl are 21 and 22
also make sure that you changed mode to I2C (those jumpers on PN532 module):
[doc - page 3](http://www.elechouse.com/elechouse/images/product/PN532_module_V3/PN532_%20Manual_V3.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I have this now working with an M5STACK grey core, the common issue was the I2C bus would lock up on a reset or re program. Use a spare I/O pin and connect to the PN532 reset pin, hold this low on boot, initialize I2C bus then drive reset high after 100mS problem solved no more bus conflicts.